# Test Connection to Linked Server is Now Failing

Tags: sql-server, excel, linked-server

I had several Linked Servers in my MS SQL Server database from which I was able to successfully query for a while. Now, when I test the connections to those linked servers, the connections are failing. The error message is:

> The test connection to the linked server failed.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "blah".
> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "blah" returned message "Unspecified error". (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7303)

My version is:
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4505224) - 14.0.2027.2 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 00:26:19   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 18362: )
My version of Office is Office 365.

I initially set up my linked servers according to: https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

I double checked my file path and it is correct. I tried dropping and re-creating my linked server but I get the same error.

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO

sp_dropserver 'blah', 'droplogins'; 

EXEC sp_addLinkedServer
    @server= 'blah',
    @srvproduct = 'Excel',
    @provider = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
    @datasrc = 'C:\myfile.xlsx',
    @provstr = 'Excel 12.0;IMEX=1; HDR=Yes';
GO
```

Comment: Perhaps the SQL Server account no longer has access to that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check permissions on the drive.
Try opening the file from the sql host or with xp_cmdshell dir

Comment: It used to work without needing to do this.  But I opened MS SQL Management Studio as an Administrator and all of the connections to my linked servers succeeded. Thank you.